# SelectedItem dependency property from IntelliBox does not update from Datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm using IntelliBox for showing autocomplete. The `SelectedItem` dependency property is implemented the following way:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(Intellibox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemChanged)));
```

This is how a new value is set in the usercontrol (IntelliBox)

```
private void ChooseCurrentItem() {
    this.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, ResultsList.SelectedItem);

    _lastTextValue = UpdateSearchBoxText(true);

    OnUserEndedSearchEvent();

    if (Items != null) {
        Items = null;
    }
}
```

The property in the viewmodel

```
private Recipient selectedRecipient;

    public Recipient SelectedRecipient
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedRecipient;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedRecipient = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecipient");
        }
    }
```

If I use the IntelliBox without a datatemplate the setter of `SelectedRecipient` is called after setting value from dependency property.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <controls:Intellibox DataProvider="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.SearchProviderRecipients}" 
                                             SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.SelectedRecipient}">
        </controls:Intellibox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately if the IntelliBox is within a datatemplate the value of the dependency property is set, but it does not call the setter in the viewmodel.

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="ListViewMain">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:Intellibox DataProvider="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.SearchProviderRecipients}" 
                                             SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.SelectedRecipient}">
                        </controls:Intellibox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

What have I have to do that the setter get called?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Where are you calling the SetValue method?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce and it has worked for me. I had UserControl with DP of type string, MainWindow Viewmodel with change notified property of type string, bound them and it has worked. Take a look into the logic how SelectedItem will be set in your Intellibox.